# FQL for Getting How a user connected to logged in user like in linked in

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

How can  I write **FQL** query for getting information on How a specific user is connected to logged in user (X degree of connection) similar to linked in as shown in the image [image]

From image the tooltip (Nuno.B is a 3rd degree connection)

Given an user ID how to find the nth degree of connection in faceBook api 2.0. Will it be possible to get this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can only determine whether two user_id are friends or not, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#userfriends